# Как правильно оформить запрос pdo с -> qoute?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, pdo

Есть код

```
    <?php

require_once 'app_config.php';
require_once 'database_connection.php';

$first_name = trim($_REQUEST['first_name']);
$last_name = trim($_REQUEST['last_name']);
$email = trim($_REQUEST['email']);
$bio = trim($_REQUEST['bio']);
$vkontakte_url = str_replace("vk.com", "vkontakte.com", trim($_REQUEST['vkontakte_url']));
$position = strpos($vkontakte_url, "vk.com");


//Массив ошибок и переменные, связанные с изображением
$upload_dir = HOST_WWW_ROOT . "uploads/profile_pics/";
$image_fieldname = "user_pic";

//Потенциальные ошибки при отправке файлов
$php_errors = array(1=>'Превышен макс.размер файла указаный в php.ini',
    2=>'Превышен макс. размер файла указанный в форме html',
    3=>'Была отправлена только часть файла',
    4=>'Файл отправки не был выбран');


if ($position === false) {
  $vkontakte_url = "http://www.vk.com/" . $vkontakte_url;
}

$twitter_handle = trim($_REQUEST['twitter_handle']);
$twitter_url = "http://www.twitter.com/";
$position = strpos($twitter_handle, "@");

if ($position === false) {
  $twitter_url = $twitter_url . $twitter_handle;
} else {
  $twitter_url = $twitter_url . substr($twitter_handle, $position + 1);
}

//Проверка отсутствия ошибки при загрузке изображения
($_FILES[$image_fieldname]['error'] == 0) or handle_error("сервер не может получить выбранное вами изображене" , $php_errors[$_FILES[$image_fieldname]['error']]);

//Является ли файл нормальным результатом отправки?
@is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$image_fieldname]['tmp_name']) or handle_error("Вы попытались обмануть, за вами уже выехали" , "Запрос на отправку: файл назывался 1" . "'{$_FILES[$image_fieldname]['tmp_name']}'");

//Дейтсвительно ли это изображение?
@getimagesize($_FILES[$image_fieldname]['tmp_name']) or handle_error("Вы выбрали файл для фото, который не является изображением", "{$_FILES[$image_fieldname]['tmp_name']}" . "не является файлом картинкой");

//Уникальное название файла
$now = time();
while (file_exists($upload_filename = $upload_dir . $now . $_FILES[$image_fieldname]['name'])) {
    $now++;
}

//Перемещаем файл на постоянное место на сервере
//@move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$image_fieldname]['tmp_name'], $upload_filename) or handle_error("Возникла проблема сохранения вашего изображения в его постоянном месте," ,"ошибка свяанная с правами доступа при перемещении файла в" . "{$upload_filename}");



////через mysqli
//$insert_sql = "INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, bio, vkontakte_url, twitter_handle) " . "VALUES ('{$first_name}', '{$last_name}', '{$email}', '{$bio}' " .
//                      "'{$vkontakte_url}', '{$twitter_handle}');";
//
//Добавить пользователя  в базу данных
//mysqli_query($mysql,$insert_sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysql));


//Вставка данных через PDO
$STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO users ( first_name, last_name,email, bio, vkontakte_url, twitter_handle) values ( '{$first_name}', '{$last_name}', '{$email}', '{$bio}', '{$vkontakte_url}', '{$twitter_handle}' )");
$STH->execute();

//Вставка изображения в таблицу images
$image = $_FILES[$image_fieldname];
$image_filename = $image['name'];
$image_info = getimagesize($image['tmp_name']);
$image_mime_type = $image_info['mime'];
$image_size = $image['size'];
$image_data = file_get_contents($image['tmp_name']);

$STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO images ( filename, mime_type, file_size, image_data) values ( '{DBH->quote($image_filename)}', '{DBH->quote($image_mime_type)}', '{DBH->quote($image_size)}', '{DBH->quote($image_data)}')");
$STH->execute();




//Отправляем пользователя на свой профиль
header("Location: show_user.php?user_id=" . $DBH->lastInsertId());
```

у меня выходит такая ошибка

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters' in /home/c/ch33404/testsite/public_html/test/scripts/create_user.php:80 Stack trace: #0 /home/c/ch33404/testsite/public_html/test/scripts/create_user.php(80): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /home/c/ch33404/testsite/public_html/test/scripts/create_user.php on line 80
```

я пробовал писать без quote вот так (80 строка)

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO images ( filename, mime_type, file_size, image_data) values ( '{DBH->quote($image_filename)}', '{$image_mime_type}', '{$image_size}', '{$image_data}')");
$STH->execute();
```

но ошибка точно такая же, подскажите где я намудрил?

Comment: вы хоть документацию то прочитайте про PDO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В дополнение к ответу @Firepro . Обычно удобнее вставлять параметры в execute - поскольку он просит ассоциативный массив на вход, что очень радует глаз:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)"); 

$stmt->execute([':name' => 'one', ':value' => 1]);
$stmt->execute([':name' => 'two', ':value' => 2]);
```

Надо заметить, что `$dbh->quote` для всех параметров запроса происходит в таком случае автоматически.

Answer (score 1):

> **Пример #1** Повторяющиеся вставки в базу с использованием подготовленных
>   запросов
>
> В этом примере 2 раза выполняется INSERT запрос с разными значениями
>   name и value, которые подставляются вместо соответствующих
>   псевдопеременных:

```
<?php 

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)"); 
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name); 
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);

// вставим одну строку
$name = 'one'; 
$value = 1; 
$stmt->execute();

// теперь другую строку с другими значениями 
$name = 'two'; 
$value = 2; 
$stmt->execute(); ?>
```

[Официальная документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php)